# Maximum number of secrets in Azure Key Vault?

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

Is there a limit on number of Keys, Certificates etc in a Key Vault?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-service-limits

Answer (score 0):

There is no documented limit for the number of resources in a Key Vault - only the number of [operations per second](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/key-vault/general/service-limits).

However, the more resources you have in a vault, the longer it will take to enumerate them all. If you have no need to enumerate them, this *may* not affect performance but also is not documented.

But if you're using a configuration library - common, for example, with ASP.NET applications - they often fetch all secrets to find the ones they need, and with a limit to the number of operations, this can either fail (too many calls) or take a long while if a retry policy is used, which built-in and enabled by default with Azure.Security.KeyVault.* packages - we recommend developers use instead of Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault, which will only get critical fixes going forward.

As common workaround is to stuff more secrets into something like a JSON blob, though make sure you want anyone with access to the blob to have access to all the secrets contained therein.